# Nested Navigation

Tags: php, mysql, navigation

I want to make a Navigation with 2 levels.

**My Code so far**

```
        <?php
        $sql = ("SELECT name, id, pid FROM tl_table WHERE pid='' ORDER BY name");
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        $list = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $list[] = $row;
        }  

        foreach ($list as $kat) {
          echo '<li><a href="#">' . $kat['name'] . '</a></li>';
        }  
        ?>
```

Nested Sets are at the moment too tricky for me.

I want at the end this.

```
<li>$kat['name']
   <li>$kat['name'] from PID</li>
</li>
```

MySQL:
http://i46.tinypic.com/35052m0.png - IMG

No I want to get the things our of the MySQL DB see the image Link.

MySQL:

```
id—–pid——name
1——0——–name1
2——0——–name2
3——0——–name3
4——3——–name3.1
5——3——–name3.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $sql = ("SELECT name, id, pid FROM tl_table WHERE pid='' ORDER BY name");
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $list        = array();
    while ($row  = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $list[$row['id']]   = $row;
       $sql      = ("SELECT name, id, pid FROM tl_table WHERE pid='".$row['id']."' ORDER BY name");
       $res      = mysql_query($sql);
       while($rw = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
          $list[$row['id']]['sub'][] = $rw; 
       }
    } 
echo "<pre>";
print_r($list); 


?>
```

Comment: Works good on line 13 is } to much
But.
I only have 1 thing in the sub Array.
But there are 2 thinks in de DB.